# Activate jQuery accordion section with validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, xval, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using xVal for client validation in an ASP.NET MVC application. Since I have too many fields in one of the forms, I split it into sections and used jQuery accordion to display one section at the same time.
Is there a way to activate the accordion section which contains validation errors when the user clicks submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it won't activate the panel but it will show it (same result)

```
            $('input#submitBuuton')
            .live("click", function() {   
                $('form').submit();     
                $('#formHolder').find('span.field-validation-error').parents('fieldset').find('legend').next().show();
                return false;
            });
```